# How do I launch SurfaceDuo Emulator from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin.forms, surface-duo

I can open and run the Surface Duo Emulator from the command line, create a Xamarin Mobile app (Android, UWP) but when I try to deploy using the Android as the Startup Project, I am unable to select the Surface Duo Emulator as an available Android Device.

There is no error msg, because the device is not available. Other Android (x86) emulators are available.

If I create and open an Android project using Android Studio, the Surface Duo is recognized and is available as a device.

I've also added the Xamarin.SurfaceDuo from Nuget.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a document about how to [use the Surface Duo emulator with Xamarin apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dual-screen/android/use-emulator?tabs=windows#xamarin-developers).

1. Find the installation location of the Surface Duo Emulator. The default location is `%USERPROFILE%\SurfaceDuoEmulator`.
2. Open the `artifacts` folder inside of the installation folder.
3. Make a backup copy of run.bat - You can copy it to something like `run_androidstudio.bat`.
4. Open the file `run.bat` in a text editor.
5. Replace the *entire* contents of the file with the snippet for your platform below:
6. Verify the `ANDROID_SDK_LOCATION` path value near the top of the file is correct (the default Visual Studio install location is specified).

Comment: Thanks Jack, That fixed it.  Make sure you have the SurfaceDuo Emulator prior to opening Visual Studio.

Comment: Since this answer was posted, the emulator download now includes a Start Menu icon specifically for Visual Studio, and batch files like run_vs.bat that should work for the default ANDROID_SDK_LOCATION used by Visual Studio/Xamarin. This is still correct (and the linked document is up-to-date)